# Can't access market place in strapi dashboard when in SuperAdmin account

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

I am starting a new project with strapi. Never used it before. So far so good but suddenly, yesterday I started getting this problem where this problem shows up:

Error that shows when I open the **Marketplace**

[image: 1]

Tried to clean build the strapi app, did nothing for the app. From the error message, it looks like I am *Unauthorized* to access marketplace. Not sure how because I am in the super admin account. So I don't even know what to do from here.

Not sure what has went wrong, if anyone has a clue or what to do to solve it, let me know. Looking forward to it, thanks!

Comment: Hi, can you post your package.json please. I think you have changed some packages version that are not matching now.

Comment: @antokhio Hmm, is that so? Alright I will keep that in mind. But as far as I remember, I just updated all of the strapi packages to 4.6.1. Maybe I installed tinymce-plugin...but that plugin didn't have an update so I don't know. 

But what I did was just start a new strapi project and shift the api folder from the old/erroring project into the new project. That worked because I just started out so didn't have too many dependencies to worry about.

Comment: everything `@strapi/` should be same version without `^`... Other stuff don't care...

Comment: *shrug* pretty sure everything `@strapi/` were on the same version, but maybe something went wrong during update. Doesn't matter now, but something to keep in mind to check for the future if it pops up again.